# Get page borders in Evince without changing overall Mate theme

Tags: linux-mint, gtk, evince

I've just noticed so it might have been like that ever since I upgraded to Linux Mint Rebecca, but I have no page borders in Evince: the white background of the page blends seamlessly into the white background of the window. There used to be a gray border around the page.

Which specific style setting controls this border? I've looked through the Mate themes, and only `Adwaita` seems to restore the border. With a bit more experimenting, I've also determined that what matters is only the GTK control style: for the `Adwaita` style only, I get the borders. The control style I'd like to keep using is `ClearlooksClassic`.